# Event doesn't render in FullCalendar v5 with eventRender. What to use instead?

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to render events in FullCalendar v5 through a JSON array but I realised that eventRender does not work for v5. How can I do it instead then? (I do know about event render hooks but didn't understand how to use that)

```
                <script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                    <?php
                    include 'config.php';
                    $items = array();
                    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM events_table WHERE grade_id = '{$studentGradeId}' ");
                    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        $items[] = array(
                            'title' => $result['event_title'],
                            'start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result['event_date'])),
                        );
                    };
                    ?>
                    var items = <?php echo json_encode($items); ?>

                    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                        headerToolbar: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
                        },
                        events: items,
                        eventrender: function(event, calendarEl) {
                            calendarEl.find('.fc-title').text(event.title);
                        }

                    });
                    calendar.render();
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: `I do know about event render hooks but didn't understand how to use that`...then you'll need to learn, because that's how you do it. There are examples available either in fullCalendar docs or in previous questions here

Comment: P.S. Your actual eventRender code seems to be redundant anyway - all you're doing is setting the title...which fullCalendar already does automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65025074/5947043 has a super-basic example of using one of the hooks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As you mention in the last comments. EventRender does not work for FullCalendar v5. It was replaced by **eventDidMount**.

I have modified your code with the latest one. Please have a look into it.

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        <?php
        include 'config.php';
        $items = array();
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM events_table WHERE grade_id = '{$studentGradeId}' ");
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $items[] = array(
                'title' => $result['event_title'],
                'start' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result['event_date'])),
            );
        };
        ?>
        var items = <?php echo json_encode($items); ?>

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
            },
            events: items,
            eventContent: function(info) {
                // Customize the event HTML here
                return { html: '<div class="fc-content">' + info.event.title + '</div>' };
            },
            eventDidMount: function(info) {
                // Add additional functionality or styles to the event element here
                info.el.querySelector('.fc-title').textContent = info.event.title;
            },
            eventWillUnmount: function(info) {
                // Clean up any additional functionality or styles here
                console.log(info.event.title + ' was removed!');
            }
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
```